# How to add another Facebook App Tab to my fanspage

Tags: facebook, tabs

I used a facebook connect app (A) in my website, and I owned anther app (B). They both have own tab.

User login as facebook though (A) in my website, and I want user add (B)'s tab page to their fanspage. How can do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities for this, i prefer the following:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=http://www.facebook.com
```

You can give that link to any user, and he will be able to add the App to his Page. you can also change the "next" parameter, but it has to be owned by the app. Does not matter anyway, it is just a redirect after success.

It does not open a dialog, so if you want to present this in your app, this solution might be better:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/

But as you commented, this does not work for other Apps. The best solution might this one then:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/

See "Adding an app to a Page", it is basically the link i have posted but with a JS popup.

edit:
Actually, there might be another option, see here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs

"You can install a profile_tab at the end of the current list of installed tabs for a page by issuing an HTTP POST request to PAGE_ID/tabs with a Page Access Token..."

Comment: thanks，i konw this way.i mean is there other ways such as js , php sdk methods can do this?

Comment: javascript method (FB.ui dialog ) can't use anther app,if use fb ui,it will process as app A

Comment: i edited my post, maybe the last solution is what you want/need. afaik there is no other way.